# js if window.location.href not match, then jump to

Tags: javascript, window.location

How to make a `window.location.href` judge?

if `window.location.href` not match `?search=`, make the current url jump to `http://localhost/search?search=car`

my code not work, or I should use `indexOf` to make a judge? Thanks.

```
if(!window.location.href.match('?search='){
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost/search?search=car';
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of things: you're missing a closing paren, and you need to escape the ? because it's significant to regular expressions. Use either `/\?search=/` or `'\\?search='`.

```
// Create a regular expression with a string, so the backslash needs to be
// escaped as well.
if (!window.location.href.match('\\?search=')) {
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost/search?search=car';
}
```

or

```
// Create a regular expression with the /.../ construct, so the backslash
// does not need to be escaped.
if (!window.location.href.match(/\?search=/)) {
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost/search?search=car';
}
```

Comment: that is right, careless `Missing a closing paren` ,the main result is `escape ?` thanks.

Comment: @Scott A: You mentioned: Use either /\?search=/ or '\?search=' in your answer but in your first example you used '\\?search=' why not '\?search=' ????

Comment: @Tarik In the first example the regular expression itself needs the backslash in it, but to represent a backslash in a string you need to escape the backslash as well... with another backslash. So \\ becomes \ when it is sent to the match() function. In the second example the /.../ construct creates a regular expression directly, and since it is not going through a string first, there's no need to escape it.